# What controls whether code stored in the data section can run or not?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, kernel, elf

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/42179

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char shellcode[] = "\x50\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x31\xf6\x48\xbb\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x53\x54\x5f\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05";

int main()
{
    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())shellcode;
    ret();
}
```

According to the comment in the code, `gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack shell.c -o shell` is supposed to compiled the code on `#1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1 (2017-03-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

I get the following error when I try the above code. How to make it work? What has been changed in the OS so that it does not work any more?

```
$ uname -a
Linux kali 5.10.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.19-1kali1 (2021-03-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack shell.c -o shell
$ ./shell
Segmentation fault
```

EDIT: It seems the problem is related with kali linux. The same binary runs on Ubuntu 64bit. I tried to step through the binary with gdb on kali.

The segmentation fault on kali is generated when the shellcode is run.

```
$ gdb -q shell
Reading symbols from shell...
(No debugging symbols found in shell)
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1129
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x1129
Starting program: /tmp/shell

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555129 in main ()
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000555555555125 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000555555555126 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
=> 0x0000555555555129 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x000055555555512d <+8>: lea    0x2efc(%rip),%rax        # 0x555555558030 <shellcode>
   0x0000555555555134 <+15>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555138 <+19>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
   0x000055555555513c <+23>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000555555555141 <+28>:    call   *%rdx
   0x0000555555555143 <+30>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000555555555148 <+35>:    leave
   0x0000555555555149 <+36>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) si 5
0x0000555555555141 in main ()
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000555555555125 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000555555555126 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000555555555129 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x000055555555512d <+8>: lea    0x2efc(%rip),%rax        # 0x555555558030 <shellcode>
   0x0000555555555134 <+15>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555138 <+19>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
   0x000055555555513c <+23>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
=> 0x0000555555555141 <+28>:    call   *%rdx
   0x0000555555555143 <+30>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000555555555148 <+35>:    leave
   0x0000555555555149 <+36>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) si
0x0000555555558030 in shellcode ()
(gdb) si

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555558030 in shellcode ()
(gdb) x/16bx 0x0000555555558030
0x555555558030 <shellcode>: 0x50    0x48    0x31    0xd2    0x48    0x31    0xf6    0x48
0x555555558038 <shellcode+8>:   0xbb    0x2f    0x62    0x69    0x6e    0x2f    0x2f    0x73
```

Using the same binary on Ubuntu, the shellcode runs correctly.

When I modify the code by putting the shellcode in the stack, then it can run on kali. So the problem is related with whether code in data can be run or not. What controls this behavior?

```
$ cat shell.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  unsigned char shellcode[] = "\x50\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x31\xf6\x48\xbb\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x53\x54\x5f\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05";
  int (*ret)() = (int(*)())shellcode;
  ret();
}
```

Comment: You [tell the linker](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002dz-keyword) that the stack should be allowed to execute with `-z execstack`, so that explains why the stack variant works. But I'm surprised that Ubuntu also marks the global variable section as executable.

Answer (score 0):

> What has been changed in the OS so that it does not work any more?

It *used to be* that readonly-data (`.rodata`) was put into the read-execute segment, together with `.text`.

To put `shellcode` into `.rodata`, you would need to make it `const`:

```
unsigned const char shellcode[] =  ...
```

I don't think the example without `const` *ever* worked.

Once you put it into `.rodata`, it will work when linking with `-Wl,-z,noseparate-code` on newer systems (if your linker doesn't support `noseparate-code`, then it is probably old enough that the example will work without any special flags).